# How to handle numerical categorical variables haivng large number of different values in python xgboost?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, xgboost, one-hot-encoding

I am trying to solve a regression problem using xgboost in python. But I have encountered a problem. I have searched it many places but not able to get any specific result.

I have a food aggregator business model. Users on my platform can order from many different restaurants.

I want to use Regression model to predict ETA for an order, (to show on app) after user places it. I am considering to use "restaurant_id" as a feature in my training model. But now the problem is I have more than 100 restaurants listed on my platform. And I cant use it numerical feature. I have to use it categorical feature. How to handle this case? ie how to handle categorical feature with so many different values in it?

I am using Xgboost in python. I have used get_dummies function of pandas. I m not sure whether to do it this way or to follow some other approach. Any suggestions will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to predict ETA using XGBoost ?

Comment: @AmeyYadav I can use any algo, xgboost is not the only one. But the idea is how to solve the issue, I m stuck in

Answer (score 0):

Sckit learn has a good class to handle those kind of task 
In your case LabelBinarizer  can do one hot encoding for you!! 
Find more   [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45365714/4683950)  , that answer can help

Answer (score 0):

Your approach with `get_dummies()` sounds OK to me, as the `restaurant_id` is a categorical feature, as you mentioned. With non-parametric tree-based methods such as random forest and xgboost, you can however even try to use the `restaurant_id` as a numerical integer feature and usually still get good performance (see answer by ogrisel here https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/5442).

This is particularly convenient when you have thousands of categories, and `get_dummies()` would result in a huge matrix.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  Feature hashing (a.k.a the hashing trick) to represent large categorical features. It is same as Onehotencoding but the sparse matrix formed is of lower Dimensions.Thus it is efficient in time and memory.