# How can I increase the accuracy of my Linear Regression model?(machine learning with python)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a machine learning project with python by using scikit-learn library. I have two seperated datasets for training and testing and I try to doing linear regression. I use this codeblock shown below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import rcParams
import urllib
import sklearn
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
df =pd.read_csv("TrainingData.csv")
df2=pd.read_csv("TestingData.csv")

df['Development_platform']= ["".join("%03d" % ord(c) for c in s) for s in df['Development_platform']]
df['Language_Type']= ["".join("%03d" % ord(c) for c in s) for s in df['Language_Type']]


df2['Development_platform']= ["".join("%03d" % ord(c) for c in s) for s in df2['Development_platform']]
df2['Language_Type']= ["".join("%03d" % ord(c) for c in s) for s in df2['Language_Type']]

X_train = df[['AFP','Development_platform','Language_Type','Resource_Level']]
Y_train = df['Effort']

X_test=df2[['AFP','Development_platform','Language_Type','Resource_Level']]
Y_test=df2['Effort']
lr = LinearRegression().fit(X_train, Y_train)
print("lr.coef_: {}".format(lr.coef_))
print("lr.intercept_: {}".format(lr.intercept_))
print("Training set score: {:.2f}".format(lr.score(X_train, Y_train)))
print("Test set score: {:.7f}".format(lr.score(X_test, Y_test)))
```

My results are:
lr.coef_: [  2.32088001e+00   2.07441948e-12  -4.73338567e-05   6.79658129e+02]
lr.intercept_: 2166.186033098048
Training set score: 0.63
Test set score: 0.5732999

What do you suggest me? How can I increase my accuracy? (adding code,parameter etc.)
My datasets is here: https://yadi.sk/d/JJmhzfj-3QCV4V

Comment: Use regularization. Apart from that: it's too broad and always depends on the data, which is not given!

Comment: If you provide the csv files people could give specific improvements.

Comment: I added datasets

Answer (score 30):

I'll elaborate a bit on @GeorgiKaradjov's answer with some examples. Your question is very broad, and there's multiple ways to gain improvements. In the end, having domain knowledge (context) will give you the best possible chance of getting improvements.

1. Normalise your data, i.e., shift it to have a mean of zero, and a spread of 1 standard deviation
2. Turn categorical data into variables via, e.g., OneHotEncoding
3. Do feature engineering:

   - Are my features collinear?
   - Do any of my features have cross terms/higher-order terms?
4. Regularisation of the features to reduce possible overfitting
5. Look at alternative models given the underlying features and the aim of the project

1) **Normalise data**

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
std = StandardScaler()
afp = np.append(X_train['AFP'].values, X_test['AFP'].values)
std.fit(afp)

X_train[['AFP']] = std.transform(X_train['AFP'])
X_test[['AFP']] = std.transform(X_test['AFP'])
```

Gives

```
0    0.752395
1    0.008489
2   -0.381637
3   -0.020588
4    0.171446
Name: AFP, dtype: float64
```

2) **Categorical Feature Encoding**

```
def feature_engineering(df):

    dev_plat = pd.get_dummies(df['Development_platform'], prefix='dev_plat')
    df[dev_plat.columns] = dev_plat
    df = df.drop('Development_platform', axis=1)

    lang_type = pd.get_dummies(df['Language_Type'], prefix='lang_type')
    df[lang_type.columns] = lang_type
    df = df.drop('Language_Type', axis=1)

    resource_level = pd.get_dummies(df['Resource_Level'], prefix='resource_level')
    df[resource_level.columns] = resource_level
    df = df.drop('Resource_Level', axis=1)

    return df

X_train = feature_engineering(X_train)
X_train.head(5)
```

Gives

```
AFP dev_plat_077070 dev_plat_077082 dev_plat_077117108116105    dev_plat_080067 lang_type_051071076 lang_type_052071076 lang_type_065112071 resource_level_1    resource_level_2    resource_level_4
0   0.752395    1   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0
1   0.008489    0   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   0
2   -0.381637   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   0
3   -0.020588   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   0
```

3) **Feature Engineering; collinearity**

```
import seaborn as sns
corr = X_train.corr()
sns.heatmap(corr, mask=np.zeros_like(corr, dtype=np.bool), cmap=sns.diverging_palette(220, 10, as_cmap=True), square=True)
```

[image]

You want the red line for `y=x` because values should be correlated with themselves. However, any red or blue columns show there's a strong correlation/anti-correlation that requires more investigation. For example, Resource=1, Resource=4, might be highly correlated in the sense if people have 1 there is a less chance to have 4, etc. Regression assumes that the parameters used are independent from one another.

3) **Feature engineering; higher-order terms**

Maybe your model is too simple, you could consider adding higher order and cross terms:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
poly = PolynomialFeatures(2, interaction_only=True)
output_nparray = poly.fit_transform(df)
target_feature_names = ['x'.join(['{}^{}'.format(pair[0],pair[1]) for pair in tuple if pair[1]!=0]) for tuple in [zip(df.columns, p) for p in poly.powers_]]
output_df = pd.DataFrame(output_nparray, columns=target_feature_names)
```

I had a quick try at this, I don't think the higher order terms help out much. It's also possible your data is *non-linear*, a quick `logarithm` or the Y-output gives a worse fit, suggesting it's linear. You could also look at the actuals, but I was too lazy....

4) **Regularisation**

Try using sklearn's RidgeRegressor and playing with alpha:

```
lr = RidgeCV(alphas=np.arange(70,100,0.1), fit_intercept=True)
```

5) **Alternative models**

Sometimes linear regression is not always suited. For example, Random Forest Regressors can perform very well, and are usually insensitive to data being standardised, and being categorical/continuous. Other models include XGBoost, and Lasso (Linear regression with L1 regularisation).

```
lr = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100)
```

**Putting it all together**

I got carried away and started looking at your problem, but couldn't improve it too much without knowing all the context of the features:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import rcParams
import urllib
import sklearn
from sklearn.linear_model import RidgeCV, LinearRegression, Lasso
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

def feature_engineering(df):

    dev_plat = pd.get_dummies(df['Development_platform'], prefix='dev_plat')
    df[dev_plat.columns] = dev_plat
    df = df.drop('Development_platform', axis=1)

    lang_type = pd.get_dummies(df['Language_Type'], prefix='lang_type')
    df[lang_type.columns] = lang_type
    df = df.drop('Language_Type', axis=1)

    resource_level = pd.get_dummies(df['Resource_Level'], prefix='resource_level')
    df[resource_level.columns] = resource_level
    df = df.drop('Resource_Level', axis=1)

    return df

df = pd.read_csv("TrainingData.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("TestingData.csv")

df['Development_platform']= ["".join("%03d" % ord(c) for c in s) for s in df['Development_platform']]
df['Language_Type']= ["".join("%03d" % ord(c) for c in s) for s in df['Language_Type']]

df2['Development_platform']= ["".join("%03d" % ord(c) for c in s) for s in df2['Development_platform']]
df2['Language_Type']= ["".join("%03d" % ord(c) for c in s) for s in df2['Language_Type']]

X_train = df[['AFP','Development_platform','Language_Type','Resource_Level']]
Y_train = df['Effort']

X_test = df2[['AFP','Development_platform','Language_Type','Resource_Level']]
Y_test = df2['Effort']

std = StandardScaler()
afp = np.append(X_train['AFP'].values, X_test['AFP'].values)
std.fit(afp)

X_train[['AFP']] = std.transform(X_train['AFP'])
X_test[['AFP']] = std.transform(X_test['AFP'])

X_train = feature_engineering(X_train)
X_test = feature_engineering(X_test)

lr = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=50)
lr.fit(X_train, Y_train)

print("Training set score: {:.2f}".format(lr.score(X_train, Y_train)))
print("Test set score: {:.2f}".format(lr.score(X_test, Y_test)))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.errorbar(Y_test, y_pred, fmt='o')
ax.errorbar([1, Y_test.max()], [1, Y_test.max()])
```

Resulting in:

```
Training set score: 0.90
Test set score: 0.61
```

[image]

You can look at the importance of the variables (higher value, more important).

```
Importance
AFP                         0.882295
dev_plat_077070             0.020817
dev_plat_077082             0.001162
dev_plat_077117108116105    0.016334
dev_plat_080067             0.004077
lang_type_051071076         0.012458
lang_type_052071076         0.021195
lang_type_065112071         0.001118
resource_level_1            0.012644
resource_level_2            0.006673
resource_level_4            0.021227
```

You could start looking at the hyperparameters to get improvements on this also: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV

Comment: Can you help me on this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47800688/how-can-i-compare-features-of-datasets-in-python

Comment: one question regarding the scaling `afp = np.append(X_train['AFP'].values, X_test['AFP'].values)` the scaler sees both train and test data. Shouldn't it only be on the X_train?

Answer (score 2):

here are some tips :

Data preparation(exploration) is one of the most important steps in a machine learning project, you need to start with it.

did you clean your data? if not start with that step!

As said in [this tutorial](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/01/guide-data-exploration/) :

> There are no shortcuts for data exploration. If you are in a state of
>   mind, that machine learning can sail you away from every data storm,
>   trust me, it won’t.After some point of time, **you’ll realize that you
>   are struggling at improving model’s accuracy**. In such situation, data
>   exploration techniques will come to your rescue.

here is some step for data exploration :

- missing values treatment,
- outlier removal
- feature engineering
- After that try to perform univariate and bivariate analysis with your features.
- use [one hot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35107559/scikit-learn-one-hot-encoding-of-string-categorical-features/45365714) encoding to transform you categorical features into numerics ones.

**this is what you need** according to what we have talked about in the comments.

[here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2015/11/easy-methods-deal-categorical-variables-predictive-modeling/) is a tutorial on how to deal with categorical variables, [one-hot encoding](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) from sklearn learn is the best technic for your problem.

Using ASCII representation is not the best practice for handling categorical features

You can find more about data exploration in [here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/01/guide-data-exploration/)
follow the suggestions I gave to you and thank me later.

Comment: I removed missing values and I transform non-numeric values to numeric values so what can I do excpet these?

Comment: I delete the rows which include null values

Comment: and to transform non-numeric values to numeric ones?

Comment: Yes, I take their ASCII values and also i gave them numeric values on both ways result is same

Comment: that is one of your first problem, as suggest in my answer try to perform one hot encoding

Answer (score 0):

1. normalize your data
2. Depending on the type of input features you can extract different features from them (feature combinations are possible too)
3. If your data is not linearly separable, you won't be able to predict it well. You may need to use another model - Logistic regression, SVR, NN / whatever

Comment: What do you mean by linearly separable ? Aren't we talking about regression?