# How to one hot encode with pandas on a new dataset?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a training data set that has categorical features on which I use `pd.get_dummies` to one hot encode. This produces a data set with n features. I then train a classification model on this data set with n features. If I now get some new data with the same categorical features and again perform one hot encoding, the resultant number of features is m < n.

I cannot predict the classes of the new data set if the dimensions don't match with the original training data.

**Is there a way to include all of the original n features in the new data set after one hot encoding?**

EDIT: I am using [sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) as my classification library.

Comment: are you using sklearn?

Comment: yes - randomforest

Comment: have a look on this https://stackoverflow.com/a/45365714/4683950

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example ,

You have tradf with column ['A_1','A_2']

With your new df you have column['A'] but only have one category 1 , you can do

```
pd.get_dummies(df).reindex(columns=tradf.columns,fill_value=0)
```